# When should an evaluation function for the minimax algorithm return negative values?

Tags: minimax

I have an evaluation function for a connect four type game. I don't understand when the evaluation function is suppose to give negative values. My evaluation function basically assigns a value for each move psuedocode might be easier to show

```
if player has 4 in a row
    return 5000;
if player has 3 in a row
    return 4000;
if opponent has 3 in a row or 3 in a column
    return 4000;
if opponent a disjoint 3 in a row or column //ie xx x
    return 4000;
if opponent has in row with spaces on both sides// ie ' 'OO' '
    return 100;
if opponent has two in arrow w/o spaces on both sides // ie XOO
    return 95;
```

This is the basic idea, however since there are no negative values, the min function always returns 0;

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

First off, your evaluation function does not have to ever give negative values. That is only a convention for simplicity that moves good for player one are positive, good for player two are negative, and equally good are zero. That should not cause your min function to return zero. If you post your min function, perhaps we can help you. My suspicion from personal experience (I made a connect four engine too) is that the min function sets the default value to zero. That will only work for the max function. The min funcion default must be set to a very high number (in the case of your evaluation numbers 5000). Otherwise, all moves it looks at will never beat zero. Just a guess